# Добавление содержимого файла в html без перезагруки сайта (HTML,JS)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Нужно реализовать, чтобы при нажатии на `Link1, Link2, Link3, etc...`, подгружалось содержимое `html` и `article`, а также менялся `url` в зависимости, на какую кнопку нажали.

```
<body>
  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="button1" tabindex="0">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a class="button1" tabindex="0">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a class="button1" tabindex="0">Link 3</a></li>
      <li><a class="button1" tabindex="0">Link 4</a></li>
      <li><a class="button1" tabindex="0">Link 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <main>
    <article id="article">
      <h1>Text</h1>
    </article>
  </main>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Пример подключения html файла в файл. 
В данном примере при нажатии кнопки в `div` с `id="acticle"' будет загружаться другой файл html, линк которого указан на кнопке.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var z = $('.button1');
    z.each(function () {
        $(this).click(function() {
            var text = $(this).text();
            $("#article").load(text);
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="button1" tabindex="0">bz.html</a></li>
        <li><a class="button1" tabindex="0">Link1.html</a></li>
        <li><a class="button1" tabindex="0">Link2.html</a></li>
        <li><a class="button1" tabindex="0">Link3.html</a></li>
        <li><a class="button1" tabindex="0">Link4.html</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<main>
    <article id="article">
        <h1>Text</h1>
    </article>
</main>
```

(старое)
Пример передачи текста в другое поле(обратите внимание на комментарии):

```js
    window.onload = function () {
        var z = document.getElementsByClassName('button1'); // Ищем все кнопки с классом

        for (let i = 0; i < z.length; i++){
            z[i].onclick = function () { //При нажатии на кнопку
                let new1 = document.getElementById('article'); // Ищем элемент с классом article
                let elem = new1.getElementsByTagName('h1'); // В нём ищем элемент с тегом h1
                elem[0].innerText = z[i].innerText; // Записываем
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="button1" tabindex="0">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a class="button1" tabindex="0">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a class="button1" tabindex="0">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a class="button1" tabindex="0">Link 4</a></li>
        <li><a class="button1" tabindex="0">Link 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<main>
    <article id="article">
        <h1>Text</h1>
    </article>
</main>
</body>
```

Comment: Простите, вопрос поставил не правильно(

Comment: @MakarX имеете ввиду код из другого файла html?

Comment: Да. На каждый линк свой html

Comment: @MakarX добавил. Соответственно файлы с такими линками должны существовать и лежать в этой же папке, где и основной файл. (И не забудьте подключить библиотеку `jquery`)

Comment: библиотеку подключил (<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>) вставил Ваш код (<script>$( document ).ready(function() { var z = $('.button1');    z.each(function () { $(this).click(function() { var text = $(this).text(); $("#article").load(text); }); });
});</script>) исправил линки. Но результата нет(

Comment: посмотрите сюда https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1079059/370904

Comment: @MakarX Значит Вы допустили ошибку при копировании.Код рабочий и протестирован. Ответ в новом сообщении на 100% точно такой же, при использовании `$("#article").load(text);` Будьте внимательнее при копировании кода.

Comment: @Тем более в данном примере копируется url из ссылки и подгружается именно этот файл.

Comment: Денис, спасибо Вам за помощь. Вопрос решил так: (<li><a href="#" onclick="$('#article').load('page1.html')">Link 1</a></li>).

Comment: Если знаете как сменить URL? Подскажите пожалуйста здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1079059/370904

Comment: @MakarX Вам уже дали там ответ, который Вы приняли.

Comment: Извините, я не понял. Мне нужно создать новый вопрос по поводу смены URL? Или как? Я не знаю как правильно здесь общаться(

Comment: @MakarX ещё раз внимательно посмотрите мой первый пример. Предположим что сам этот файл называется `index.html` У Вас в этой же папке должны находится файлы `bz.html`, `Link1.html`, `Link2.html`, `Link3.html` и так далее. Ещё раз протестировал - всё работает.